# Rails Params in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hello i know this is common problem but i cant let it work.. I need account activation from email link.. url looks like `http://domain.tld/activation/name@domain.tld/d4sa89dsa98` and i want access that parameters from controller :-)

**routes.rb**

```
match "activation/:email/:activation_key" => "frontend#activation", :via => :get
```

**frontend_controller.rb**

```
  def activation
    @user = User.find(:conditions => {:email => params[:email], activation_key => params[:activation_key]})
    render "activation"
  end
```

and im getting **error**

```
No route matches [GET] "/activation/name@email.tld/a46d4sa8dsa68d"
```

my **activation.html.erb**

```
<% if @user %>
Activation successful.
<% else %>
Activation key is invalid.
<% end %>
```

**EDIT: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I replaced :email parameter with :id parameter because it look nicer, im not sure if 
`Array.new(32){Random.new.rand(36).to_s(36)}.join` is unique string but that does not matter now.

**route**

```
match "activation/:id/:activation_key" => "frontend#activation", :via => :get
```

**rake routes**

```
GET    /activation/:id/:activation_key(.:format) frontend#activation
```

**frontend controller**

```
  def activation
    @user = User.find(:conditions => {:id => params[:id], :activation_key => params[:activation_key]})
    render "activation"
  end
```

**error**

```
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

but this **WORKS** so the problem is in the condition

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

**SOLUTION**

```
@user = User.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => params[:id], :activation_key => params[:activation_key]})
```

Comment: Why do you have the email in there? I have never seen that before. I would only use the activation key if I were you.

Comment: you are absolutely right, i wasnt sure about uniqueness of that generator so i add email but id of user will be better or i can use `SecureRandom.uuid`.. i changed :email to :id but now it says `Couldn't find User without an ID` that means `params[:id]` doesnt work.. i will edit question for more information

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding a `constraints: { email: /[^\/]+/ }` to your `match` argument? Possibly the `.` gets eaten up by overly greedy regex.

Comment: Hello thanks, i replaced email for id.. please look edited question